# Are CW complexes absolute neighbourhood extensors?

Tags: general-topology, cw-complexes

Are CW complexes absolute neighbourhood extensors?

A topological space $K$ is an absolute neighbourhood extensor (ANE) if for every space $X$, closed subset $A\subseteq X$, and continuous map $f:A\rightarrow K$, there is an open neighbourhood $U\subseteq X$ of $A$ and an extension $\tilde{f}:U\rightarrow K$ of $f$.

If one restricts the spaces $X$ in the above defintion to normal Hausdorff spaces, are CW complexes examples of ANE's?

I ask because I frequently see the kind of neighbourhood extension property described above used in proofs regarding the cohomological dimension of spaces.

Comment: Isn't this in Hu?

Comment: See [this](http://nlab-pages.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nlab/show/absolute+retract) and its references. It seems to hold for finite-dimensional ones.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma if it is I wouldn't know as I don't have that text.

Comment: There are such things as libraries. My university had it on the shelves. It’s a standard reference.

Comment: Please make the bodies of your MSE questions self-contained and don't rely no the title of your question for important information. One very good reason for this is that some interfaces to MSE (e.g., the Android app) don't render MathJax in the title.

Comment: Metrisable CW complexes are in ANE(paracompact). Countable metrisable complexes (hence finite complexes) belong to ANE(normal). In general CW complexes belong to ANE(stratifiable), and hence to ANE(metric). There are countable, finite-dimensional CW complexes which do *not* belong to ANE(paracompact), and hence not to ANE(normal).

Comment: @Tyrone thank you. Thats what I was looking for.

Comment: Since you mentioned (co)homology, note that every CW complex has *homotopy type* of an ANE (and vice versa).